# There arent no auto compleet suggestions for android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in xml editor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I can't get suggestions android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in the xml editor in android studios, this only happen for the android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView, for the other standard elements there is no problem and i can see the suggestions. Here is an image of how this is represented in android studios:
 [image: no suggestions for android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView]

Im using `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+'` and

```
minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

any idea how to fix this and get the suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Is this happening with other custom views too? If yes, I'd suggest cleaning your project (Build menu > Clean project) and invalidate caches (File > Invalidate cache and restart)